# How to loop through json with python?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to pull json into a python3 list and loop through it. There must be a semantic error in the code I do not understand as the print of the loop will not get the desired item:

```
my_json = '
{
    "1": {
        "small": "small 1",
        "large": "large 1",
    },
    "2": {
        "small": "small 2",
        "large": "large 2",
    },

}'
data = json.loads(my_json)


for result in data:
    print(data['small'])
```

I do get the following:

```
>>> for result in data:
...     result
... 
'1'
'2'
```

This looks pretty straight forward to me, what am I missing?

Comment: It is a dict, you need to loop over ```data.items()``` Or loop over ```data.values()```

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: `data` is a `dict`. Try `pprint.pprint` to visualize the structure of `data`.

Comment: The amount of items is never the same. I added the output of the for loop to the question. How would I loop through the dict to access "large" and "small"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you expect the `small` result from `my_json`. JSON have a nested dictionary so you first need to find all values then from the value take only small result

```
import json

my_json = '{"1": { "small": "small 1", "large": "large 1" }, "2": { "small": "small 2","large": "large 2"} }'
data = json.loads(my_json)

for result in data.values():
    print(result['small'])


# OUTPUT

# small 1
# small 2
```

Or, you can try this

```
for key, result in data.items():
    print(result['small'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `data` is a dictionary, you can't just iterate through it getting the nested dictionaries like you're trying to do, as `for result in data` will iterate over `data`'s keys. You can iterate through this list of all of the dictionary's keys and get the data that way. Here's an example of what that would look like

```py
for result in data.keys():
    print(data[result]['small'])
```

If you print `result` your current for loop, you can see it prints `1` and `2`, the same values that my for loop will print. So removing the `.keys()` from my loop will also work.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this works but the solution from mhhabib is slightly smaller in code. I learned somehting today from you. Thankk you.